# django_currentuser alternatives or how to get current user in Models.py

Tags: django, django-models, model

I have 2 Models in my django models.py.

I need to get data from model2 to model1, but I don't need to store it anywhere in the model1 fields. I found @property of django and implemented that. My issue was that I need to get who the user is using request.user, which is not possible in models.py

So how can I access user in django models? Is there any other packages? or is there any inbuilt django way which I haven't thought about?

I searched and got a package called `django-currentuser` , unfortunately i'm using Django 4 which doesn't have a support.

Comment: Please show the code you tried.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get exactly what's your problem.
if you want to get the current user in django,this should be handled in your views like:

```
def View(request):
 user = request.user
```

and if the other model that you got data from have any field connected to User like:

```
user = models.Foreignkey(User,...)
```

you can easily achive the user...

please describe more...